# how to put image into a page from a json object?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm writing a news site and with all the news stored in json files. Here's an example of the json Schema:

```
{
title: "lorem ipsum",
body: "Qui Quo Omnis Nulla Porro Quidem Quisquam Consequuntur Neque Expedita Iu [image1 goes here]. Nditiis Mollitia Facere Adipisci Fugiat Minus Vero Nostrum Sint Se. I Et Culpa Vitae Quos Ullam Optio Est Debitis Reprehenderit Alia. Dolorem Necessitatibus Accusantium Voluptatibus Maiores Dolores Quae Velit Te. Tur Non Officia Assumenda Obcaecati Veritatis Minima Dicta Im [image 2 goes here]",
author: "author",
images: ["path/to/image1","path/to/image2]
}
```

How can i make images appear in the right position?
(i'm using nunjucks templating engine if it's usefull for the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your json schema if possible.

```
{
  "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
  "bodies": [
    {
      "text": "Qui Quo Omnis Nulla Porro Quidem Quisquam Consequuntur Neque Expedita Iu",
      "image": "path/to/image1"
    },
    {
      "text": "Blah blah blah",
      "image": "path/to/image2"
    }
  ],
  "author": "author"
}
```

Then you will know that the image should always go after the text. You can even add an empty text to begin with an image.

Edit: Just for fun, I put together a short script that creates an array with the news' text and the image that goes after. I still think you should instead update your schema.

```
var myNew = {...}
var magic = myNew.body.split(/\[.*?\]/).filter(n=>n);
var whatsthis = magic.reduce((fullArray,text, index)=>{
    fullArray.push(text);
  fullArray.push(test.images[index]);
  return fullArray;
}, []);

console.log(whatsthis);
```

This outputs `["Qui Quo Omnis Nulla Porro Quidem Quisquam Consequuntur Neque Expedita Iu ", "path/to/image1", ". Nditiis Mollitia Facere Adipisci Fugiat Minus Ve…ia Assumenda Obcaecati Veritatis Minima Dicta Im ", "path/to/image2"]`.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lfpab33y/

If it makes things easier, you can change

```
fullArray.push(text);
fullArray.push(test.images[index]);
```

into

```
fullArray.push({type:"text", content:text});
fullArray.push({type:"imagePath", content:test.images[index]});
```

so you know whether it's text or imagePath and do something about it in your template.